# error starting Oracle HTTP Server

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-server-2003

I instaleded Oracle HTTP Server on Windows Server 2003 and It's work. But when I restart computer, I get error.
service.log:

```
Request failure: 0 of 1 processes started.

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content

Content-Length: 683

Content-Type: text/html

Response: 0 of 1 processes started.

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='US-ASCII'?>
<response>
<opmn id="CIST_WEB_TEST:6200" http-status="204" http-response="0 of 1 processes started.">
  <ias-instance id="standalone">
    <ias-component id="HTTP_Server">
      <process-type id="HTTP_Server">
        <process-set id="HTTP_Server">
          <process id="833224729" pid="2752" status="Init" index="1" log="C:\oraHTTP\opmn\logs\HTTP_Server~1" operation="request" result="failure">
            <msg code="-21" text="failed to start a managed process after the maximum retry limit">
            </msg>
          </process>
        </process-set>
      </process-type>
    </ias-component>
  </ias-instance>
</opmn>
</response>
```

and HTTP_Server~1

```
--------
14/07/03 13:38:44 Start process
--------
Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.2.0.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server running...

--------
14/07/03 13:38:46 Start process
--------
[Thu Jul 03 13:38:46 2014] [warn] pid file c:/orahttp/apache/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.2.0.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server running...
```

Answer (score 0):

If installed Oracle HTML Server 10.2.0.1.0, you need disable the service OracleOraDb10g_homeASControl and restart

Administrative Tools>Services>OracleOraDb10g_homeASControl0>Startup type:Disable and Service status: Stopped

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer!